# selected value from the listbox in php

Tags: php, listbox, selectedvalue

I want the value which I select from the `listbox` and want to store in php variable because I want to use that variable for further use. Please help..

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
   <?php
     include('dbconnect.php');
     db_connect();

     $query = "SELECT * FROM test_customer"; //Write a query
     $data = mysql_query($query);  //Execute the query
   ?>
   <select id="cust_name" name="mylist" onchange="selectedvalue()">
   <?php
     while($fetch_options = mysql_fetch_array($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
   ?>
   //Added Id for Options Element 
   <option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['test_id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo   $fetch_options['cust_name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['cust_name']; ?></option><!--Echo  out options-->

  <?php
    }
  ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you save it in a php variable once you process the form using $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="cust_name" name="mylist" onchange="selectedvalue(this.value)">
```

access that values `selectedvalue(val)` in parameter

get that selected value and store it in input type= hidden as u need it for further use..

Comment: is there any option without onchange event?and can you please show how i store that value in php variable?

Comment: u want to post that variable? or how/why u want to use it? so i can simplify code

Comment: i want to pass that value in another query so that according that i can make another listbox.

Comment: use AJAX for it..so u can change selection_list_2 on change of selection_list_1..

Comment: sir i didnt get you actually i want another listbox of states having same customername and then the cities also

Comment: sorry bt can u plz explain wat exact ur need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store into a php-variable, you must post the form. I've added a submit-button below. You also must speciy an action to where the form is submitted to: action="whatever.php"

```
  <form name="myform" method="post" action="whatever.php"> <!-- added action here -->   

  <?php
     include('dbconnect.php');
     db_connect();

     $query = "SELECT * FROM test_customer"; //Write a query
     $data = mysql_query($query);  //Execute the query
     ?>
     <select id="cust_name" name="mylist" onchange="selectedvalue()">
     <?php
     while($fetch_options = mysql_fetch_array($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
     ?>
     //Added Id for Options Element 
     <option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['test_id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo   $fetch_options['cust_name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['cust_name']; ?></option><!--Echo  out options-->

     <?php
     }
     ?>
     </select>

     <!-- added submit button -->
     <input type="submit" value="ok" />

     </form>
```

Create a php-file called whatever.php and in this file, store the value into `$cust_name` by doing this:

```
<?php
$cust_name = $_POST['mylist']; //mylist is the name of the select-list
?>
```

If you want to post the form without having to reload the page, you must use something called ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me.Try this example.**

```
 public function getAptTypesBySelectedKy($valKy) {
        $stmt = "SELECT ap_typ_ky, ap_typ_desc FROM apt_types WHERE ap_stat=1 order by ap_typ_desc";
        try {
            $con = DataHandler::connect();
            $values = $con->prepare($stmt);
            if ($values->execute()) {
                echo '<select class="form-control" name="type" id="apt_types_slc">';
                while ($row = $values->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    if ($valKy === $row['ap_typ_ky']) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['ap_typ_ky'] . '" selected>' . $row['ap_typ_desc'] . '</option>';
                    } else {
                         echo '<option value="' . $row['ap_typ_ky'] . '">' . $row['ap_typ_desc'] . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo 'Error on apartment types';
            $error = $ex;
            print_r('<pre>' . $ex->getCode() . '</pre>');
            print_r('<pre>' . $ex->getMessage() . '</pre>');
        }
    }
```

**In your html form page.**
`$__typKy = $_RA['typeky']` //this line get the selected value from database and set as parameter to the function `getAptTypesBySelectedKy()`

```
    <?php
          $__typKy;
          if (isset($_RA)) {
              $__typKy = $_RA['typeky'];// you need to find this key from database.
              //this is the selected value key of `<select>`
              }
              $var = new DataHandler();
              $var->getAptTypesBySelectedKy($__typKy);
    ?>
```